# If f is not surjective then f|C is not surjective.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I have a function $f:A\to B$ and a subset $C \subseteq A$. The restriction of $f_{|C}: C\to B$ is a function such that $\forall z(z\in C\implies f_{|C}(z)=f(z))$

I want to proof that if $f$ is not surjective then $f_{|C}$ is not surjective.

This is really confusing me, because I thought that if a function was not onto, then we cannot guarantee that it is not onto in every subset of its domain.

However I did come up with a proof which I am not completely sure if it's correct, but I'd like to understand why the statement in the title is true for this specific question (I understand that it will not work for most other functions).

I worked it out from the formal definition of surjectivity: $\forall b\exists a(f(a)=b)$, $a$ being a member of $A$ and $b$ being a member of $B$. Suppose that $a\in C$. Then $f(a)=f_{|C}(a)$. We know that $f$ is not surjective, so we can guarantee that $f_{|C}$ is not surjective. Suppose that $a\notin C$. Then $f(a)=f_{|C}(a)$ or $f(a)\neq f_{|C}(a)$. $f_{|C}(a)$ is not defined because $a\notin C$, so we cannot guarantee that there is at least one $a$ such that $f(a)=b$.

The last part seems specially confusing to me.

Comment: The image of $f|C$ is a subset of the image of $f$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is easier to prove the transposition of this statement:

> If $f\restriction_C$ is surjective, then $f$ is surjective.

Given any $b \in B$, there exists $a \in A$ such that $f\restriction_C(a) = b$, hence $f(a) = b$, and $f$ is surjective. $\blacksquare$

If you don't believe in transposition, you can reverse the logic of the above proof:

Suppose that $f$ is not surjective, then $\exists b \in B\mid \forall a \in A, f(a) \neq b$. Hence $\forall a \in C, f\restriction_C(a) \neq b$. $\blacksquare$

Comment: I think I understand it now. In a function like $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, $f(x) = x^2$, restricting the domain won't make it surjective. I was confusing injectivity and surjectivity a bit.

Answer (score 1):

$C\subseteq A\implies f(C)\subseteq f(A)$, so  $f(A)\neq B\implies f(C)\neq B$.

Answer (score 0):

"$f$ is not surjective $\Rightarrow$ $f_{\vert C}$ is not surjective" is equivalent to "$f_{\vert C}$ is surjective $\Rightarrow$ $f$ is surjective".

Now, we show that $f_{\vert C}$ is surjective $\Rightarrow$ $f$ is surjective.
By hypothesis, for every $y\in B$, there exists $x\in C$ such that $f_{\vert C}\left(x\right)=y$ since $f_{\vert C}$ is surjective. Since $C\subseteq A$ and $f_{\vert C}$ is a restriction of $f$, for every $y\in B$, there exists $x\in C\subseteq A$ such that $f\left(x\right)=f_{\vert C}\left(x\right)=y$, and so $f$ is surjective. Thus, the proof is completed.